# cs50 pset2 caesar, either getting segmentation fault or incompatible conversion

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code so far, for the [`caesar` problem from problem set 2 of CS50](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/2/caesar/):

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2 && check_integer(argv[1]) == true)
    {
        int key = atoi(argv[1]);
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        string ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plaintext); i < n; i++)
        {
            char a = plaintext[i], b;
            if (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')
            {
                if (a + (key % 26) > 'Z')
                {
                    b = a - (26 - (key % 26));
                }
                else
                {
                    b = a + (key % 26);
                }
            }
            if ((a >= 'a' && a <= 'z'))
            {
                if (a + (key % 26) > 'z')
                {
                    b = a - (26 - (key % 26));
                }
                else
                {
                    b = a + (key % 26);
                }
            }
            ciphertext[i] = b;
        }
        printf("ciphertext: %s", ciphertext);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The problematic part is only the ciphertext string. With this current code it says conversion from char b to string chiphertext[i] is incompatible. So I tried removing the array when intializing and initialized it to NULL but then it said segmentation fault. And there is also another error where it says it can't print ciphertext because format suggests it's a character while I put a string stronghold. What do I do?

Here's [a picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlrMQ.png).

Comment: What is the `string` type?

Comment: @DanielWalker not sure but i think 'char *' because that's what it says in the error

Comment: If that's true, then `ciphertext` is an array of `char` pointers.  Therefore, assigning a single `char` when it's expecting a pointer is going to give you trouble.

Comment: Could you show the full error?

Comment: @DanielWalker edited in the pic of the errors

Comment: Don't you want `string ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];` to provide room for the `'\0'` character so `cyphertext` can be treated as a string in `printf("ciphertext: %s", ciphertext);`??

Comment: @DanielWalker The question is tagged `cs50` and thus the `string`  type definition comes from [`cs50.h`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/develop/src) used by Harvard's CS50 course.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Did not know that.

Comment: The course seems to have become quite popular in the last few months, or maybe I only just started noticing.... It can be difficult to help students with this material because it really is a [whirlwind tour](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/).

Comment: OP: Based on the lecture notes up to this point, the intended solution involves **not creating** a separate string. Instead, you are supposed to output *each character* of the ciphertext *as it is computed*. Hint: do you remember the `%c` formatting code?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes after reading David's comment and Daniel's reply I tried using ciphertext as a character rather than a string and gave the output character by character. Turns out i just complicated stuff by trying to output the whole string. And after giving it a bit more thought removed the ciphertext and just output b character by character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `string` is a `typedef` for `char*`, `ciphertext` is an array of `char` pointers.  Therefore, assigning a `char` when it expects a pointer is going to have bad results.

You really don't want `ciphertext` to be an array of `string`s.  You want it to be another string with the same size as `plaintext`.  You can do this with

```
string ciphertext=malloc(strlen(plaintext)+1); // The +1 is for the null-terminator.
```

Also, I would calculate `strlen(plaintext)` once inside of twice.  Do

```
n=strlen(plaintext);
string ciphertext=malloc(n+1);
```

Comment: not sure how that worked, havn't learnt all that yet but it works now. thanks a lot!

Comment: David, that's true.  However, he would need `char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)+1];`.